# Increase font size of inplot mean for ggbetweenstats from ggstatsplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I increase the font size of the mean in the plot when using ggstatsplot? ggbetweenstats in particular?

I can change the font size for everything using the code below, except the mean in the actual plot.

```
  ggplot.component = list(theme(text = element_text(size = 21))))
```

[image]

Code to generate above plot

```
ggbetweenstats(
  data = iris,
  x = Species,
  y = Sepal.Length,
  title = "Distribution of sepal length across Iris species"
)
```

Comment: What do you mean by the "mean"? An actual example would be helpful.

Comment: How to control the font size of the mean (average).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set the font size and style the labels via `centrality.label.args`:

```r
library(ggstatsplot)

ggbetweenstats(
  data = iris,
  x = Species,
  y = Sepal.Length,
  title = "Distribution of sepal length across Iris species",
  centrality.label.args = list(size  = 8)
)
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a method to display less texts in the subtitle? for example, I want to show only p value in the subtitle, others such as confidence interval and t and g values are not needed.

Comment: @Z.Zhang TBMK I'm afraid no. You could only turn the subtitle on or off via `results.subtitle` but there is no option to choose which test statistics to include in the subtitle.