# Increase font size of inplot mean for ggbetweenstats (R) but not write it over the plots

Tags: r, fonts, size

If you use the code below to increase the font size of inplot means, the means are written over the plots (see the picture in answer in [Increase font size of inplot mean for ggbetweenstats from ggstatsplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68638594/increase-font-size-of-inplot-mean-for-ggbetweenstats-from-ggstatsplot)). I would like to increase the font size, but still have the means next to the plots as in the picture in question in [Increase font size of inplot mean for ggbetweenstats from ggstatsplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68638594/increase-font-size-of-inplot-mean-for-ggbetweenstats-from-ggstatsplot)). Is that possible?

```
library(ggstatsplot)

ggbetweenstats(
  data = iris,
  x = Species,
  y = Sepal.Length,
  title = "Distribution of sepal length across Iris species",
  centrality.label.args = list(size  = 8)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `nudge_x` or `nudge_y` argument to specify where the label should be. Maybe you want something like:

```
library(ggstatsplot)
ggbetweenstats(
  data = iris,
  x = Species,
  y = Sepal.Length,
  title = "Distribution of sepal length across Iris species",
  centrality.label.args = list(size  = 7, nudge_y = 1.5)
)
```

Output:

[image]

Keep in mind that because of the really big font size, it is hard to place the labels in a clean way. You can manually change the argument if you want.